# Mysql: can a query be served by Btree and geospatial index?

Tags: mysql, indexing, geospatial, r-tree

We use mysql 5.7 to store geospatial data. A table contains 5 columns store_id (String), tenant_id (String), type (enum), status(enum), boundaries (Multipolygon). The boundaries column has only one polygon but the type was set as MultiPolygon.

Our query has

```
SELECT  DISTINCT store_id
    FROM  ${boundariesTable}
    WHERE  tenant_id = '${tenantId}'
      AND  status = '${status}'
      AND  type <> 'Z'
      AND  ST_Contains(boundaries, GeomFromText(
                 'Point(${coords.lng} ${coords.lat})'))
```

This DB call is very slow when boundary data has circles with several geolocation points. Hence, we want to use a geospatial index for the boundaries key. Would we need to modify the above query to use a geospatial index for the boundaries column? If yes then how should we structure the query? Without other parameters like type and tenantId, the number of rows increases multifold. So I am apprehensive to remove all other constraints and retain only the ST_Contains part of the query.

Thank

---

Comment: Provide the structure as comlete CREATE TABLE script. Also specify the approximate  rows amounts: total, matched ST_Contains only, matched all another conditions only, matched the whole query.

Comment: And please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`